# check availability of meeting rooms in outlook with python

Tags: python-3.x, outlook

I am working on to write a python script to check if particular meeting room is available. If yes then meeting room will be booked, if not then python will find available time slot for that day.

For now, I have achieved to book meeting room but I am not able to check availability of rooms.

To book any meeting room, i have to send mail to that book meeting room configured mail id and corresponding acceptance/decline mail I receive as per the availability.

below is the snippet :

```
import win32com.client
import datetime
import pywintypes

oOutlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
appt = oOutlook.CreateItem(1)
appt.Start = '2018-05-18 13:30'
appt.Subject = 'Follow Up Meeting'
appt.Duration = 30
appt.Location = '<name of meeting room>'
appt.MeetingStatus = 1
myRecipient = appt.Recipients.Add("<mail id of meeting room")
myRecipient.resolve
my_date = datetime.date(2018,5,18)
pywintypeDate = pywintypes.Time (my_date)
availabilityInfo = myRecipient.FreeBusy(pywintypeDate,30,True)
print(availabilityInfo)
#   appt.Save()
#   appt.Send()
#   print("done")
```

output is :

`000000000000000000000222222200222222022000000000000000000000000000000002222222222220000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022000000000000000000000000000000000000000002220002222200000000000000000000000000000000002220022022222000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002222000000000000000000000000000000000000220000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000222222200000000000000000000000000000000002220000022000000000000000000000000000000000000002220000222222000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022000000000000000000000000000000000000000002220022022200000000000000000000000000000000000022000022000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002222000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022022200000000000000000000000000000000002220002222000000000000000`

so is it first byte (0) indicate time slot from 00:00 to 00:30 and soon for one complete month ?

Is it possible to get output only for one day ?

Do i have to parse the above output to check availability for my particular required time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appt.Recipients.Add` returns the `Recipient` object. Resolve it first (`Recipient.Resolve`), then call [Recipient.FreeBusy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/recipient-freebusy-method-outlook).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i have edited above snippet as per your suggestion, FreeBusy is a good method, but its making my life little complicated giving me result of complete one month based second parameter(MinPerChar), which i was trying to cross check with the meeting slots available and the information was not correct. will the timing start from 00:00 midnight or how it is.  I have added few more doubts in the question, please guide me through the same. Thank you sir :)

Comment: Yes, the first parameter is date - the time portion is ignored, so it always starts at midnight.

Comment: so is it first byte (0) indicate time slot from 00:00 to 00:30 and soon for one complete month ?

Is it possible to get output only for one day ?

Do i have to parse the above output to check availability for my particular required time ?

Comment: one more question, in the above example, availabilityInfo contains output from 18-May-2018 00:00 to 17-June-2018 23:59, including all weekends ( sundays), right ?

Comment: Correct. A single character corresponds to 30 minutes if you specify 30 as the second parameter. The example uses 60*24, so one character corresponds to one day. Not exactly very granular.

Comment: To extract just one day, assuming you specified 30 as the second parameter, copy the first 48 characters - that would be 24 hours of the day specified as the first parameter.

Comment: hi, i noticed one thing, there are different return of freebusy function sometimes. it is something i am missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: Hi, i have asked my query in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441215/outlook-freebusy-method-giving-incorrect-output  please have a look.